# HTML5 video background - strange layer on top?

Tags: css, html, video

I am trying to add a video background to a page and have 2 problems/questions.

1. I want the video stay in a div at the top of the page vs stay in full browser window (what is happening now)
2. The video only appears after scrolling down the page. Almost as if there is a div over top. Can't figure it out.

Here is HTML and CSS:

```css
.section-content {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
#section1 .section-container {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: ;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
video { 
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url('') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}
#section2 .section-container {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: ;
}
#section3 .section-container {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: ;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="bgvid">
  <source src="http://callmenick.com/_development/video/full-screen-background-video/media/demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<nav>
  <div class="container-nav">
    <a href="#" class="navabout">?</a>
  </div>
</nav>

<section id="section1">
  <div class="section-container">
    <div class="section-content">
      <h1>Main headline is here</h1>
      <h2>Sub headline is here about stuff.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="section2">
  <div class="section-container">
    <div class="section-content">
      <p>Assertively synergize enterprise-wide</p>
      <p>Globally exploit value-added mindshare for B2C synergy. Authoritatively orchestrate technically sound meta-services and revolutionary infrastructures. Assertively synergize enterprise-wide communities before adaptive internal or "organic" sources.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: For accessibility reasons, you should **never autoplay a video**, neither in the background, nor in the foreground.

Comment: Why are you not showing the `div` you want to contain the video then?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe He is using the video as an animated background image, so why would auto-playing it cause any accessibility concerns?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe that's bullshit... we still build stairs, but we offer an _alternative_, called elevators. Accessibility is not about avoiding awesome stuff, it's about making sure it still works when users - for whatever reason - don't have access to your awesome stuff

Comment: @giorgio Check [success criterion 2.2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/time-limits-pause.html) in the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines. It it plays for more than 3 seconds, it needs a control to stop or pause it.

Comment: @connexo & giorgio See [Why Autoplay is an accessibility issue](https://www.abilitynet.org.uk/news-blogs/why-autoplay-accessibility-issue).

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I can see your argument, still I do think that in this specific case autoplaying the video does not involve accessibility issues. None of the problematic scenarios mentioned in the article you referenced apply here imo.

Comment: @connexo If it's longer than a few seconds, it does. See [success criterion 2.2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/time-limits-pause.html) in WCAG 2.0: "Moving content can also be a severe distraction for some people. Certain groups, particularly those with attention deficit disorders, find blinking content distracting, making it difficult for them to concentrate on other parts of the Web page."

Comment: "I want the video stay in a div at the top of the page" - **where is that `div`**?

Comment: So in your opinion all content on the web should be accessible for everyone? What about people that don't speak the page's language? "*All textual content must be available in all languages since some people may find it hard to access content written in a language they do not know.*" Honestly, I'm, generally all for accessibility and participation, but some rules are just plain bullshit.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Yes, that may be true, but in that case it is a design choice if you commit yourself to it. A music website is not well suitable for people with hearing disabilities. As is my super-cool-photographs for people with sight problems. If you're building a website with non-critical content, you may very well make the sophisticated decision that some people cannot enjoy your website. Too bad for some, but super-awesome for others. The same reason as for why you are still proceeding with your design choice although you know 1 out of 1.000 people will not like it.

Comment: @giorgio Design decisions that do not create accessibility problems are awesome. Design decisions that do create such barriers willingly are just stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer for 1)** 
Change your video `position:fixed` to `position:absolute` to keep it at the top.

**Answer for 2)**
Probably the video takes time to load due to external link and also large size. Try downloading the video and put it in your web resources folder to load it locally and also see if the size can be reduced of the video if its big. (Need more detail on this to solve as not able to reproduce sample: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/full/rWjxeN/)

**[Edit for issue # 2] - User found the problem and fixed on his own**

**Comment from M Hamilton:** Got it! Had height:100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; in a body tag. Removed these and it works fine.

Comment: 2) Its not an issue of load time. When I implement 1) i can see the video loaded and playing underneath a div (the video is slightly higher than the div).

Comment: hmm. Can you share a screenshot. Cause with your code i am unable to reproduce issue # 2.

Comment: Got it! Had `height:100%; margin: 0;  padding: 0;` in a body tag. Removed these and it works fine. Thanks for your help @Nasir-T

Comment: Great. I have edited the answer to include your comment in it for problem # 2 in case someone else needs help in future.

Answer (score 0):

If the video in the example is representative of what you want to use (i.e. it is longer than just a few seconds and it has audio), **you should not autoplay the video**, and definitely not without providing quick-to-reach keyboard-accessible controls that allow the user to stop it!

Here is why:

- Some people, especially blind people, use a [screen reader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader) to access web content (and their computer or smart phone in general). Most screen readers use **speech synthesis** to tell the user what's on the page. **When audio (or video containing audio) starts playing automatically, it will interfere with the screen readers speech output.** So, if you do use audio that plays automatically, make it very short (at most a few seconds) and/or make sure that it is easy to pause or stop (a keyboard-accessible control for this should be very easy to reach). See [Understanding Success Criterion 1.4.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-dis-audio.html) in the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 2.0.
- Some people get **distracted by moving content** and then have difficulty interacting with the web content. See [Understanding Success Criterion 2.2.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/time-limits-pause.html) in the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 2.0:

  > (...) Content that moves or auto-updates can be a barrier to anyone who has trouble reading stationary text quickly as well as anyone who has trouble tracking moving objects. It can also cause problems for screen readers.
  >   Moving content can also be a severe distraction for some people. Certain groups, particularly those with attention deficit disorders, find blinking content distracting, making it difficult for them to concentrate on other parts of the Web page. (...)

See also [Why Autoplay is an accessibility issue](https://www.abilitynet.org.uk/news-blogs/why-autoplay-accessibility-issue) on AbilityNet (October 2015).

Comment: That is not actually the video I'm planning to use. Mine is actually much longer but no audio. But yes, I hear you. Was planning to still auto-play but add in keyboard controls.